# Program/Service to manage Golf club

Tags: information-management

I'm looking for a solution or solutions that can work together that can handle these features for a Golf Club:

- Manage memberships
- Booking salons
- Tee times
- Manage food and beverage sales to members and guests
- Pro Shop POS. Prices must be different for members and non-members.
- Club restaurant/cafeteria POS
- Inventory and warehouse management
- Event management
- Accounting and finance
- Human resource management
- CRM
- Fixed Asset management
- Procurement management

This kind of solutions exists?